# TypeScript: compare two enums by string

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have 2 enums:

```
enum Insurer {
  PREMERA = 'premera_blue_cross',
  UHC = 'united_health_care'
}

enum ProductSource {
  PremeraBlueCross = 'premera_blue_cross',
  UnitedHealthCare = 'united_health_care'
}
```

I try check if array of Insurer includes ProductSource:

```
const insurerArr: Insurer[] = [Insurer.PREMERA, Insurer.UHC]
insurerArr.includes(ProductSource.PremeraBlueCross)
```

But got an error from the TS compiler:

```
Argument of type 'ProductSource' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Insurer'.
```

There is a way to compare without do a casting to `string` and then to the other enum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider to switch to `type` instead of `enum`:

```
type Insurer = 'premera_blue_cross' | 'united_health_care';
type ProductSource = 'premera_blue_cross' | 'united_health_care';
const insurerArr: Insurer[] = ['premera_blue_cross', 'united_health_care'];
insurerArr.includes('premera_blue_cross');
```